# Dynatrace: what is the meaning of srv in dtCookie Cookie set by UEM

Tags: performance, monitoring, dynatrace, rum

I have a website where UEM is activated.

It adds this cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: dtCookie==3=srv=6=sn=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=perc=100000=ol=0=mul=1; Path=/; Domain=.foo.com
```

I would like to know the meaning of srv. 
Is it a number for server or something else ?

I didn't find in documentation any information on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the ID of the cluster server node that is supposed to correlate that user session.

It's undocumented, since it's an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I upvoted, but before accepting , I need a clarification, I am supposed to have 3 servers but srv ranges from 1 to 6 ? Is this regular ? Can you explain ? Thanks

Comment: No, these ID's are not gapless counts. So, seeing a 6 in a 3 server setup is totally fine. Sometimes these ID's reorganize, e.g. when server nodes restart during rolling updated.

Answer (score 2):

It's not related to the number of servers as I have seen the values higher than the number of servers. Something internal to DynaTrace and as you correctly said there is no documentation for this.